Packet marking not working for ICMP and UDP
For context, I'm configuring a VPN on a web proxy server (let's call it "SERVER1") using policy-based routing and iptables. I have two interfaces on SERVER1:

eth0 for local network -- local network on which I have a client "CLIENT1" with which I want to send HTTP requests to SERVER1
nordlynx for the VPN

I want to mark all packets on eth0 with the value 0xe1f1 so that I can route the traffic (TCP, UDP, ICMP) between SERVER1 and CLIENT1 to the local network directly and not go through the VPN (which would not work obviously).
So far, I've ended up with this, which is working (CLIENT1 can send an HTTP request to SERVER1 and gets a response) for TCP when combined with net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept=1:
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j MARK --set-mark 0xe1f1

That's my first issue: why do I need to enable net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept in order for this to work? I find the documentation of this setting quite confusing:

If set, incoming connections to listening sockets that do not have a socket mark will set the mark of the accepting socket to the fwmark of the incoming SYN packet. This will cause all packets on that connection (starting from the first SYNACK) to be sent with that fwmark. The listening socket’s mark is unchanged. Listening sockets that already have a fwmark set via setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_MARK, ...) are unaffected.
Even without that setting enabled, if I mark each packet using the firewall, why would I need anything else?

Then, my second issue is that ICMP (and probably UDP) traffic is not working: the ping command just hangs. Worse, it seems there is no such thing as icmp_fwmark_accept or udp_fwmark_accept.
I guess I'm missing something, but I can't figure out why...
I think it's not really needed to answer the question, but for context, here are my routing rules:
root@c4858f58bc0b:/# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xe1f1 lookup 205
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default


TCP creates connections (notice from the SYN segment). ICMP and UDP are explicitly connectionless, meaning no UDP datagram or ICMP IP packet relates to a connection the way TCP segments do.
